# Short Story ID: Beginning of telepathic humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telepathy

I believe I read a short story in the 50's about the beginning of telepathy in humans. The enemies were breaking into the location as the couple telepathically married themselves just before being killed.

Anyone have a clue to this written missive?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: What were the enemies? Government people, aliens, other telepaths, etc? What was the location they broke into?

Comment: Quite possibly you are looking for Heinlein's "Gulf" discussed previously at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87936/short-story-where-a-man-disguises-the-destination-of-a-letter-by-making-postal-c (with a very different set of remembered facts).

Answer (score 4):

Could this perhaps be 'Gulf' by Robert Heinlein?

The story is not so much about the development of telepathy in humans, though the story does cover the 'improvement' of the human race via various means.

The bit that I feel matches is that the two main characters Joe and Gail Green speak marriage vows telepathicly just as the bad guys kill Gail and Joe then completes his part of the mission (he does not survive).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this story was "Gulf" by Robert A. Heinlein covered in the 4-story anthology (1953) Assignment in Eternity.