# Heinlein short story about Mr & Mrs Joseph Green saving the moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In one of Heinlein's short stories, two characters wind up saving the moon (or perhaps the universe).  The character Beetle Kelly (sp?) was involved.
What was the title, and in what collection did it appear?

Comment: The character you may remember is "Kettle Belly," a nickname that Gregory/Dr. Horace Baldwin goes by as part of his alter-ego.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87936/short-story-where-a-man-disguises-the-destination-of-a-letter-by-making-postal-c

Answer (score 5):

Based on the names, I think there's a good chance you're thinking of the novella, "[Gulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_(novella))" ([ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41342+1)), first published in *Astounding* in 1949.

> The story postulates that humans of superior intelligence band together, and keeping themselves genetically separate, create a new species. In the process they develop into a hidden and benevolent "ruling" class. The story invokes the notions of the General Semantics of Alfred Korzybski and the work of Samuel Renshaw to explain the nature of thought and how people could be trained to think more rapidly and accurately. The material on human intelligence and self-guided evolution is intermixed with a more standard "secret agent" adventure story.
>
> The driver of the plot is the "nova effect", which can initiate a chain reaction that consumes an entire planet. The last remaining documentation of the process is recorded on microfilm that the Federal Bureau of Security wants to obtain. The antagonist is "Mrs. Keithley", a deranged woman who happens to be one of the richest people in the Solar System, and who wants to use the nova effect to blackmail most of humanity, so she can rule from her home on the Moon.
>
> "Joe" is a secret agent who is tasked with getting the microfilm. Returning to Earth, he is captured and finds himself confined with a man who calls himself "Kettle Belly" Baldwin. Using only two packs of playing cards to encode words, they communicate while under observation and plot their escape. Baldwin introduces Joe to his group of superior individuals and trains him in their advanced techniques of thought, even attempting telepathy. Baldwin reveals that he and his group work to keep dangerous science and technology out of the hands of common humans, for their own protection. The nova effect was discovered by Baldwin and implemented by his own people as part of an attempt to prove it could not be done.
>
> Joe meets Gail, another agent, with whom he falls in love. Baldwin receives a warning that the nova effect is set to be triggered on Earth, but the triggering device is on the Moon. Joe and Gail are sent to disable the trigger so the device on Earth can be attacked. Gail has to get the remote control from Mrs. Keithley while Joe is charged with disabling the transmitter. The situation becomes desperate. Joe and Gail unexpectedly achieve telepathic rapport. Gail kills Mrs. Keithley, while Joe contends with the certainty that the transmitter is booby trapped. Knowing that they are both about to die, they telepathically recite their own private marriage vows before each being killed.

As per DavidW's comment, the story ends with:

> The letters on the metal marker read: TO THE MEMORY OF MR. AND MRS. JOSEPH GREENE WHO, NEAR THIS SPOT, DIED FOR ALL THEIR FELLOW MEN

Found with a search for *heinlein "joseph green" moon*

Comment: If (and only if) this answer (or any others someone might post) is the story you are looking for, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Please do not feel obliged to accept a wrong answer just because it's close.

Comment: That sounds like it.  I've just ordered a paperback copy on line. THanks.

Comment: Last line of the story: "The letters on the metal marker read:

TO THE MEMORY OF MR. AND MRS. JOSEPH GREENE WHO, NEAR THIS SPOT, DIED FOR ALL THEIR FELLOW MEN"

Comment: You beat me by the time it took me to find my copy. :)

Comment: FWIW:  [ISFDb entry](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41342+1) showing publications (mostly various editions of *Assignment in Eternity*) and original publication in Astounding: [Part 1, Nov 1949](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v44n03_1949-11_cape1736/page/n52), [Part 2, Dec 1949](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v44n04_1949-12_cape1736/page/n53)

Comment: @DavidW: I will happily yield my answer. No one should be penalized for proper research.

Comment: Not at all; the offer is extremely generous, but not necessary.  It's not like I'm hard-up for rep. :)  That's why I posted the useful bits (especially the links) as comments.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then it is a duplicate of [this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87936/short-story-where-a-man-disguises-the-destination-of-a-letter-by-making-postal-c)